# NancyFx and TinyIoc

Tags: c#, rest, nancy

I am new to dependency injection.I am having problems understanding how to use the nancyFx bootstrapper and TinyIoc. I want to reference a dependency but can not understatnd how to do it. I can not seem to find the correct info anywhere or I am just misunderstanding it.This is my code:

```
  public class Startup1
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseNancy();
    }
}
```

My interface:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Getname();
}
```

My implementation:

```
public class Person : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Getname()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

My program

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.Name = "Bill";
        string uri = "http://localhost:8080/";
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup1>(uri))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Stopping");
        }

    }
```

My nancy bootstrapper:

```
public class MyNancyBoot : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        //base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
          container.Register<IPerson>(new Person());

    }
}
```

My nancyModule:

```
public class MyNancyModule : NancyModule
{
    public MyNancyModule(IPerson person)
    {
        Get["/"] = _ =>
        {
            var x = TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<IPerson>();
            return "OK";

        };
    }
}
```

This return an error in MyNancyModule.

```
 var x = TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<IPerson>();
```

Ok so how do I get my person into MyNancyModule?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything, Nancy should automatically pick up these dependencies for you..

Comment: Can confirm I created a dummy app and didn't need to hook up the interfaces manually. I have added a simple project to my GIT page https://github.com/OnamChilwan/NancyFx-Concept hopefully pretty self explanatory. Shows an interface implemented with no custom bootstrap uses the default one and Nancy automatically detects this.

Comment: Ok thanks the reason why I wants a custom bottstrapper because it was taking a long to  start nancy in my other project.

Comment: You can still have the custom bootstrap but don't need to explicitly specify your dependencies as long as there is only one implementation of it.

Comment: I've run your nancyFx-Concept thank you but the person object in my module is instantiated but the name field is null. Is it possible to use the already instantiated person the main program entry?

Comment: They live in two separate parts in your system? You can have it as a static field in your Programs.cs and reference it that way..

Comment: Totally confused. Can I put it this way. If I had a wrapper class for the Nancy service how can I get data from nancy to the wrapper? Sorry about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111412/discussion-between-dr-schizo-and-paul-stanley).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to reference a dependency but can not understatnd how to do it.

I think there are a couple of things to look at here.

You are mistakenly thinking that you need to somehow pass in, on the controller constructor, any type you may want to return from your Get["/"] controller operation. This is not the case. If one of the service operations happens to return a Person type, you do not need to inject that person type into the constructor. Rather you could just do something like:

```
Get["/"] = _ =>
    {
        var x = new List<Person>();
        return Response.AsJson(x); 
    };
```

Obviously this service operation is of very limited use, as it will always return an empty list of type Person.

So what you need is a dependency which gets Persons. Eg:

```
interface IGetPersons
{
    List<Person> GetAll();
}
```

In order for this to be used inside the controller, Tiny Ioc will need to know about it. So that is where you can then register this type with Tiny Ioc.

```
container.Register<IGetPersons>();
```

This brings us onto the second thing you are struggling with, which is how Tiny Ioc works.

After you add the implicit registration in the nancy bootstrapper, Tiny Ioc will then scan your assemblies and find the implementation of IGetPersons automatically! (This is assuming there is a single implementation. If more than one you will actually need to do more work but that's another story).

This magic then allows you to just modify your controller thus:

```
public MyNancyModule(IGetPersons personGetter)
{
    Get["/"] = _ =>
    {
        var x = List<Person> personGetter.GetAll(); // Look, don't need to resolve this manually!
        return Response.AsJson(x);
    };
}
```

Tiny Ioc will take care of resolving the injected type to the IGetPersons implementation, which you are then free to use through the controller.

> Lets say a client makes an http post to a win form app which is
>   running a nancy service. How do get the data from the nancy service to
>   the win form.

Have a look at the following: http://weblogs.asp.net/rweigelt/10235654

The author is using the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) to make changes to what I assume is some kind of singleton provided by the framework:

```
container.Register(MefContainer.GetExportedValue<IRemoteAccess>());
```

Comment: I am not sure we are understanding each other.Lets say  a client makes an http post to a win form app which is running a nancy service. How do get the data from the nancy service to the win form.

Comment: @PaulStanley - this is actually a completely different question to the one you asked above. I think you should just create a new question for this.

Comment: In answer to your question there is no way I know of to directly call out to the hosting container, other than by manipulating some kind of static resource, either in-memory or a file etc, to which both have access.

Comment: @PaulStanley there may be a way but I don't know of one. That is why I think you should create a new question asking this specifically, someone else may know a way to make it work.

Comment: Ok will raise a new question.

Comment: Sorry Tom but is it possible to to pass a instantiated object to the container?